# Redis memory usage results are not as expected

Tags: redis

I am using

> Redis version=6.0.5, bits=64

Here is the order of command execution：

```
hset zq eee  rr1
info memory -> used_memory:1064704
hset zq eep  rr2
info memory ->used_memory:1064704 
hset zq eei  rr3
info memory ->used_memory:1064720 
hset zq eeu  rr4
info memory ->used_memory:1064736   
hset zq eeu  rr5
info memory ->used_memory:1064736
```

My expectation is to allocate 16 memory and use 10，But not like this
10 here refers to `2 *  (prev_len(1)+encoding&len(1)+content(3))`

Answer (score 0):

[INFO MEMORY](https://redis.io/commands/info) is taking into account none relevant memory allocation.
You should use [MEMORY USAGE](https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage).

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset zq eee  rr1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY USAGE zq
(integer) 65
127.0.0.1:6379> hset zq eep  rr2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY USAGE zq
(integer) 75
127.0.0.1:6379> hset zq eei  rr3
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY USAGE zq
(integer) 85
127.0.0.1:6379> hset zq eeu  rr4
(integer) 1
```